# iOS keychain access on device based on Provisioning profile

Tags: ipad, ios5, app-store, keychain

I have written an iPad (iOS 5+) app that saves the GTM-Oauth library to save the oauth token to the keychain. Based on the existence of the auth token, I perform different actions in my view controller:

```
//Fetch the auth token from keychain
GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth = [self myCustomAuth];

//perform actions:
  if (auth) {
    BOOL didAuth = [GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch authorizeFromKeychainForName:@"My App: Custom Service" authentication:auth];
    // if the auth object contains an access token, didAuth is now true
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier..]
  }
  else {
   //do something else
  }

//The customAuth method:
- (GTMOAuthAuthentication *)myCustomAuth {
  NSString *myConsumerKey = @"abcd";    // pre-registered with service
  NSString *myConsumerSecret = @"efgh"; // pre-assigned by service

  GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth;
  auth = [[GTMOAuthAuthentication alloc]    initWithSignatureMethod:kGTMOAuthSignatureMethodHMAC_SHA1
                                                  consumerKey:myConsumerKey
                                                   privateKey:myConsumerSecret] ;

  // setting the service name lets us inspect the auth object later to know
  // what service it is for
  auth.serviceProvider = @"Custom Auth Service";

  return auth;
}
```

While the segue works fine (i.e auth exists in the keychain and returns true) when I codesign the app using my development and adhoc distribution profiles, it doesn't work when using the appstore distribution profile, and has been rejected by Apple for 'exhibiting bugs'.

I checked the entitlements for the appstore profile using the command (from Apple docs):

```
security cms -D -i /path/to/the.app/embedded.mobileprovision
```

and under entitlements, i can see:

```
<key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>{My Bundle seed identifier}.*</string>
    </array>
```

Can someone let me know what could be the problem, and how to ensure keychain access in my appstore build?